# Is US patent 1816592 still active? Can I repatent it?

Tags: patent-lifetime, us1816592

Is the patent [US1816592](https://www.google.com/patents/us1816592) “Means to recuperate the atmospheric moisture” still active?

- How can I find out whether this patent is still active?
- Is it possible to repatent this invention?

Comment: You can find the expiration date of a patent here: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/how-do-you-determine-a-patent-expiration-date-us-7-055-282-b2

Comment: And you can find information on re-patenting something here: http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/14281/10011

Comment: The answer is no and no.